# Hudson: where to download file and stop specific builds running?

Tags: php, hudson, hudson-api

I have a file that is generated inside (hudson server) `/var/lib/hudson/jobs/jobtitle/1/out.txt`

I need to fetch this file, but doing a GET request for `http://myhudson:8090/job/jobtitle/1/out.txt` doesn't actually locate the file.

Basically, I have another box that will grab  this file from the hudson server. This box will make the out.txt file available for download.

Another challenge is the build number directories. How would I be able to use the hudson API to stop or delete the specific builds running ?

I am forced to do iterate through all build numbers to send STOP or DELETE api call in php using wget to do the REST API call. This is not very efficient.

```
for ($i=0; $i < 3000; $i++){
exec('wget -O /dev/null "http://myhudson:8090/job/' . 'jobtitle' . '/$i/stop"');
}
```

Comment: These jobs you have to stop using the API, are you sure they have their triggers well set? I find surprising to have to stop them manually... About exposing the files so the other system can fetch them, I am copying the resulting files/packages to a folder served by Apache HTTPD as part of the publishing process at the end of the job. But that's for leaving the file available for some people to manually download it. If that's easier in your situation, you can also think of a way to push the produced file to the other computer instead (FTP or something...).

Comment: yeah I am now using the apache method....how can I stop the jobs ? seems like looping through the build is not working as planned.

Comment: If you want to stop the current build try using "lastBuild" as the build number. That is the current build running.

Comment: that works beautifully ! I would accept the above answer/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to stop the current build try using "lastBuild" as the build number. That is the current build running.